# Avro messages with schema

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

So we are planning to use Avro for communication over a confluent kafka-based ecosystem. My current understanding of Avro is that each message carries its schema. If that is the case, we need schema registry just for resolving version updates?

I ask since carrying the schema with each message prevents the need for something like a schema registry to map a message id to a schema. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the Confluent Schema Registry, the Kafka messages published with the Confluent Avro Serdes library do not contain the avro schema. They only contain a numeric Schema id that is used by the consumers deserializer to fetch the Schema from the Confluent Schema Registry. These schemas are cached by the serializer and deserializer as a further performance optimization.

Comment: thanks --- so a non schema registry based message will still carry the schema at the start, right? It does make you wonder (separate question I know) how the receiver can write a code for an unknown TLV like data.

Comment: An Avro serialized message will have one extra byte at the beginning of the message which is its schema id in the schema registry and then the rest of the message is the normal binary avro data. Very compact on the wire and much smaller message size than putting the entire avro schema in every message.

Comment: @intiha Depending on the serializer implementation that is used, *a non schema registry based message **will*** have the schema in each record (key and value, if both are Avro encoded).